# How to do Selenium Testing with multiple threads?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, threading

I'm trying to do functional testing using Selenium Webdriver.

I'm using ruby code to test on multiple windows at the same time using multi-threading

The problem is when the thread creates the new window, the other window will lose focus and the send keys process from that window fill stop and the test fails.

How can I handle this window focus issue?

Thanks

Note: every browser window has its own driver instance

**Update** :

here How I create the thread

```
begin
    while testIndex < testCases.length #  End when every testcase has been tested
        if(Thread.list.count<threadLimit+1) # if thread slot available 
            th[testIndex] = Thread.new(testIndex){ |i| # Create Thread
                # get testCase input
                # initiate driver and run test
                # I have wraper for this, and there is no thread inside it, just single thread code
            }
        end
    end

    th.each{|t| 
        if(!t.nil?)
            t.join # Wait unfinished thread
        end
    }
rescue Exception => e
    puts "MESSAGE: #{e}"
end
```

**Update II**

Trying to investigate the issue again based on @Leon comment.
and it's work, but just in Chrome
it's failing in IE, FF, dan Phantom

The errors such as :

- CSRF token error (IE) - already using cleanSession and private, work on single thread test so it's not the web code error, this make selenium fail to find element which caused the script stoped,
- Unable to bind to locking port 7054 (Firefox),
- Unable to bind to locking port 8909 (Phantom)

**Update III**

Updated my selenium to 3.4 , the errors is gone. But the weird things is only phantomjs don't execute it concurrently.

Comment: Updates title to be about multiple windows.  It said browsers which made me think of firefox, chrome, Safari, etc.

Comment: Are you using capybara ?

Comment: nice icon also btw

Comment: @Michael I'm using plain selenium webdriver

Comment: What you used exactly to initiate multi-threading,what your relevant code looks like? I  use java for my tests and by  making tasks that include the testing code I want (on their own driver instance) and feeding them to a multiple thread executor work just fine. If every browser window has its own driver instance, what you described shouldnt happen, being on focus isnt a requirement to run selenium be it single-threaded or multi-threaded. You should be able to have the windows in background and they should work just fine.

Comment: Hi @Leon , updated my question. But thanks for your explanation, I'll check it again.

Thank you

Comment: hmm , already invetigated it. and it's weird. it's work when I use it to test my aplication in my PC and fail when trying to simple google search in my laptop. using same code ..

Comment: And it's just work on Chrome, can't use IE or firefox and phantom , the errors such as CSRF token error (IE) - already  using cleanSession and private , unable to bind to locking port 7054 (Firefox),  unable to bind to locking port 8909 (Phantomjs)

Comment: This is what test frameworks are good at, like **junit**, **rspec**, **testng**, etc... They do the multithreading stuff for you so all you have to worry about it creating the driver per test.

Comment: well actually I need to create it per test.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/choudharylakshyaveer/SeleniumThreadedAutomation.git

Please review this, I have used multithreading based programming to run several web drivers

Comment: Hi thanks for the example. but are you already test it using phantomjs? because the problem is when executed on phantomjs driver.

This is an old problem, I already abandon it, it's better using framework after all I guess :). but thanks for your answer

Comment: I use selenium for the scraping purpose only and this code works good with chrome. I have not tested it for phantomjs.